# Present login view controller modally in swift tabbed application

Tags: swift, appdelegate, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a view controller modally from my app delegate, however, I'm receiving the below error. When creating my project I chose a tabbed application. I need help resolving this error and presenting the view controller. Would also appreciate code to dismiss the view controller too

```
2018-10-03 20:28:57.324 App[74397:2825933] Warning: Attempt to present <App.SignUpViewController: 0x7fbd7b608c60> on <UITabBarController: 0x7fbd7b407620> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    showSignUpView()
    return true
}

func showSignUpView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let signUpViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SignUpViewController") as! SignUpViewController
    signUpViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.fullScreen
    signUpViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.coverVertical
    window?.rootViewController?.present(signUpViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: You say "I'm receiving the below error" but there doesn't seem to be a error shown below?

Comment: The error is - 2018-10-03 20:28:57.324 App[74397:2825933] Warning: Attempt to present <App.SignUpViewController: 0x7fbd7b608c60> on <UITabBarController: 0x7fbd7b407620> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Comment: It appears to me that you're trying to show the sign up view too early in the lifecycle of the app. A state at which rootViewController is not ready to present something. Try running showSignUpView() later. Also this seems like a weird approach, your main class shouldn't be responsible for presenting/dismissing modals

Comment: As the error message says at that point in the application life cycle the `UITabBarController` has not been added to the view hierarchy.  You are going to have to move the sign up presentation logic to later probably as part of the main root view controller itself.